# UIAppearance not styling the custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios

This is kind of strange issue! I am using the UIAppearance API to style my UITableViewCells. I use the following code to style the UITableViewCell.

```
// table cell
    id tableCellAppearance = [UITableViewCell appearance];
    [tableCellAppearance setBackgroundView:[theme imageViewForTableViewCellBackground]];

// table cell
-(UIImageView *) imageViewForTableViewCellBackground
{
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [backgroundView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile_heading_background"]];

    return backgroundView;
}
```

When I run the app and see the UITableViewCells only 1 cell is styled in the UITableView. The cell in the middle. Why is that?

Comment: where you calling this method imageViewForTableViewCellBackground?

Comment: Just a helper method to get the UIImageView to be set as the background for the UITableViewCell. The above code is only called once in the App delegate. I believe the problem is that the cells are dynamically generated and the appearance API does not support applying styles to the dynamically generated controls.

Comment: why not you implement a CustomTableViewCell?

Comment: I actually did implement a custom table view cell but I want to style it using the UIAppearance API since I have many custom cells.

Comment: you could show the code for that? because you need to implement <UIAppearance> Protocol

Comment: UIAppearance Protocol.. hmm I will need to look into that! Thanks for the direction but it does apply the background image to a single UITableViewCell (custom cell) displayed in the UITableView control.

Comment: you could check my answer, it could help your cause

Answer (score 2):

Create a `CustomUITableViewCell` and implement the `<UIAppearance>` Protocol

**CustomCell.h**

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell <UIAppearance>

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIColor *backgroundCellColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize backgroundCellColor;

-(void)setBackgroundCellColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}
```

Finally use the **CustomCell** in your view and set background or image

```
[[CustomCell appearance] setBackgroundCellColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Sweet! I will try it out. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I tried it and it did not worked out. I tried to change the backgroundView of the UITableViewCell but it does not apply style to all the UITableViewCells.

Comment: @johndoe try this [tutorial](http://46media.net/xcode-turorials/customize-the-appearance-of-uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-in-xcode-4/) it has working code with video

Comment: it is not what you are looking for? I have used it in my application and it works ok, did you try it?